# How can I (literally) open a file with Node?

Tags: node.js, command-line

I'm creating a command-line utility with Node that will be able to open (launch) files for the user programmatically, using the application they would use to do so by default.

After reading through the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback), I don't think fs.open() can do that.

Is there any way to do this in Node without having to pull in shell scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to call a special OS-dependent program via [`child_process.exec()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). On Windows you'd use `start`, for OSX you'd use `open`, and for Linux you'd generally use `xdg-open`. You might look at using an already made module on npm for handling all these cases, such as [open](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open).